# Python input interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
test = input( '> ').strip()
if test == 'PRINT' :
    print( test )
else :
    print('FAILURE')
```

How do I get my mini interpreter to say HELLO WORLD if I type PRINT 'HELLO WORLD'

Comment: you should be using raw_input()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
test = input('> ')
command, _, args = test.partition(' ') if test else (None, None, None)
if command == 'PRINT':
    print(args[1:-1])
else:
    print('FAILURE')
```

Running this and entering `PRINT 'HELLO WORLD'` will result in your shell printing out `'HELLO WORLD'`

Comment: raw_input? only input works for me, Is there a way to only out put the text between the ' '

Comment: @UserBOBBED You must be using Python 3, just replace `raw_input` by `input`. And yes it is possible, see edited answer (just slice off first and last characters).

Comment: Thanks this is great

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the **split** method of strings.  You give it a dividing character; you get back a list of the divided strings.  For instance,

```
divide = test.split("'")  # Single quotation mark is the divider
```

Gives you the list

```
["PRINT ", "HELLO WORLD"]
```

Can you finish from there?